# Linux-kernel: printk from "open" syscall don't work

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, system-calls, printk

I have a doubt.

I opened the kernel and I changed the directory linux-3.1.1/fs/open.c

I changed the follow code  in the open.c.

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(open, const char __user *, filename, int, flags, int, mode)
{
    long ret;
    printk(KERN_EMERG "Testing\n");
    ... 
}
```

**I put this line only: `printk(KERN_EMERG "Testing");`**

And I include the libraries:`<linux/kernel.h>` and `<linux/printk.h>`

So I compiled and rebooted my linux(Ubuntu).
During the rebooting appeared a lot of **"Testing"** on the screen.
So up to now its Ok.

---

But now I have a problem.
I created this program in c.

```
int main()
{
    size_t filedesc = open("testefile2.txt",O_CREAT | O_WRONLY,0640);
    printf("%d",filedesc);
}
```

I compiled this program and executed and works good.
But I don´t understand why the **"Testing"** didn't appeared on the shell.
I mean , if when I reboot the pc appeared a lot of the word "Testing" , why this word doens´t appear when I execute the program above.
Just to add I include this libraries in this code above:

`unistd.h` , `fcntl.h` , `stdio.h` , `stdlib.h`

Thank you guys.

Comment: I tried fixing the formatting on this, but it seems I made it worse.  Anyone see where it's screwed up?  I don't see anything wrong with the way the code blocks are formatted...  :(

Comment: I think its better now.Sorry,I didnt know how to use this format correctly.Thank you.

Comment: Maybe your `printk()` isn't appearing where you expect it to appear. When you open another virtual console (or terminal) and type `sudo tail -f /var/log/dmesg`, do you see your `Testing` messages?

Comment: Mike is probalby correct. Your shell is run under a different process than the console that the kernel is connected to. Ubuntu almost certainly redirects the output to the system log.

Comment: When I type this sudo tail -f /var/log/dmesg doesnt appear "Testing"                                                             Basically I`m open a shell and typing this:gcc -o t test.c
And then : ./t                                                    But  its prints only 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But I don´t understand why the "Testing" didn't appeared on the shell.

I think, this is effect of  printk's messages suppression. (more exactly:*rate limiting*)

Check the messages log or console for

```
printk: ### messages suppressed.
```

string.

This feature will stop printing a message, if there were a lot of messages in recent time.

Actual code is  as 3.1 kernel: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.1.1/kernel/printk.c#L1621

```
1621 * printk rate limiting, lifted from the networking subsystem.
1622 *
1623 * This enforces a rate limit: not more than 10 kernel messages
1624 * every 5s to make a denial-of-service attack impossible.
1625 */
1626 DEFINE_RATELIMIT_STATE(printk_ratelimit_state, 5 * HZ, 10);
1627
1628 int __printk_ratelimit(const char *func)
```

So, As the `open` syscall is very-very popular (just do an `strace -e open /bin/ls` - I'll get 15 `open` syscalls for just starting an simplest `ls`), the rate limiting will be in effect. It will limit your message to be printed only one time in 5 seconds; not more than 10 messages in single "burst".

I can only suggest to create a special user with known UID and add an UID checking before `printk` in your additional printk-in-open code.

Comment: In fact , I want that the shell prints the word "Testing",because I want to do some tests with system call.                          Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Sorry , I think  understood the comment now.

Comment: message from printk will not be printed by shell. It is printed by kernel on some text console (which is opened by Alt-F1) and also saved in `dmesg` buffer and also sent to `syslog` daemon. You just doing more printk, than is allowed to be printed. You should add some condition before printk, because `open` is one of most used syscall. You should only printk for case you are interested in, e.g. by testing UID or path.

Comment: Well,Could you suggest me what I can put before printk(KERN_EMERG "Testing\n") to show the "Testing"?
I didnt understand so well what I can put in the code.Thanks

Comment: [   24.295775] audit_printk_skb: 30 callbacks suppressed
Is this the problem?

Comment: `if(current->uid == YOUR_SPECIAL_UID) { printk(...);}` and also you can lower limits in `/kernel/printk.c` file at `DEFINE_RATELIMIT_STATE(printk_ratelimit_state, 5 * HZ, 10)`. Change it to ... `DEFINE_RATELIMIT_STATE(printk_ratelimit_state, HZ, 100)` - it is 100 messages per second limit. Do both changes. The `30 callbacks suppressed` is not a problem, it just says that there are a lot of messages generated by your printk, and the problem is very high rate of printk messages.

Answer (score 6):

**printk** calls appear in the kernel message buffer, not in your process' stdout/stderr

Comment: Could you tell me how I open the kernel message buffer and see the word "Testing"? Because I am not "finding" it.Thank you.

Comment: @UserJ use the 'dmesg' command, or look in one of the syslog logs (under /var/log/ )